# Скрипт автоматического добавления строки Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Необходим скрипт, который будет автоматически добавлять новую строку, после заполнения первой ячейки столбца А.
То есть я ввёл что-то в ячейку А2, автоматически добавилась строка А3. Ввёл значение в А3, автоматически добавилась строка А4 и так далее

Comment: У меня в профиле контакты -- пишите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для добавления строк можно использовать методы **insertRows, insertRowsAfter, insertRowsBefore** класса [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet). Ну и конечно, для автоматизации процесса потребуется [триггер onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite).

В итоге код может быть примерно таким:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editedRange = e.range, row = editedRange.getRow();
  editedRange.getSheet().insertRows(row + 1, 1);
}
```

При этом скрипт будет добавлять строки при любом изменении данных в любой ячейке листа, не только в колонке A. Тем не менее, он решает ту задачу, которая сформулирована в вопросе.

Comment: Попробовал. Спасибо, работает. Только у меня 14 столбцов, и если я в каждом начинаю править что-то, добавляется 14 строк. Это не совсем то, что я хотел бы....

Comment: Верно. Но Вам никто не мешает поставить условие `if (editedRange.getColumn() == 1)` перед строкой добавления ряда.

Comment: Точно! Туплю. Спасибо большущее!!!